# How to find quantile from frequency data?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, quantile

Suppose I have a table of data where customers have purchased things as such:

```
Customer|Price|Quantity Sold  
a       | 200 |   3.3  
b       | 120 |   4.1  
c       | 040 |   12.0  
d       | 030 |   16.76
```

This is supposed to be a crude representation of a table of data, with customer, price, and quantity sold for the *same* product.

I want to figure out how to calculate the median purchase price for this info.

I'm getting a little confused on methodology because I get that getting a quantile in pandas is easy as `data[row].quantile(x)`

but since each row really represents more than one observation, I'm unsure how 
get quantiles.

edit: On top of that, the major problem is that quantity sold is not discreete. It's a continous variable. (We're like talking meters, kgs etc, so creating more rows isn't an option.)

Comment: Can you create an expanded Series with `Quantity` repeats of each  `Price` value, and take quantiles of that?

Comment: unfortunately, the quantity items are actually continous variables..  which makes it even more complex.

Comment: Create a pd.Series, and it has the **describe()** method. Try it, you will find it very very useful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a set of discrete values, the median is found by sorting and taking the central value. However since you have continuous values of `Quantity`, it seems like you're really looking for the median of a probability distribution, where `Price` is distributed with relative frequencies given by `Quantity`. By ordering the data and taking the cumulative `Quantity`, we can come up with a graphical representation of your problem:

[image: Cumulative distribution]

You can see from this plot that the median value is 40 (y value at the X midpoint). This should be expected since the quantities sold at the two lowest prices are very large. The median can be calculated from your dataframe as follows:

```
df = df.sort_values('Price')
cumul = df['Quantity Sold'].cumsum()
# Get the row index where the cumulative quantity reaches half the total.
total = df['Quantity Sold'].sum()
index = sum(cumul < 0.5 * total)
# Get the price at that index
result = df['Price'].iloc[index]
```

Any other quantile for the same data can be calculated using a different ratio of the total.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the quantity sold and add each item to a big list_of_all_sold (there are other ways to do this as well, this is one example):

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
p = [200, 120, 40]
qs = [3,4,12]

list_of_all_sold = []
for i in range(len(qs)):
    for x in range(qs[i]):
        a.append(p[i])
```

Then, Python 3.4+ has a statistics package you can use to find the median:

```
from statistics import median
median(list_of_all_sold)
```

EDIT for finding median of continuous quantity supplied:

You could make a pandas dataframe then sort the dataframe by price, then find the median number and subtract off the quantity sold at each price point in the sort dataframe, going row by row until you find the median point. Something like this:

```
c = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
p = [200, 120, 40, 30]
qs = [3.3, 4.1, 12.0, 16.76]
# Create a pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price' : p, 'qs' : qs}, index = c)
# Find the index of the median number
median_num_idx = sum(qs) / 2
# Go down dataframe sorted by price
for index, row in df.sort_values('price').iterrows():
    # Subtract the quantity sold at that price point from the median number index
    median_num_idx = median_num_idx - row['qs']
    # Check if you have reach the median index point
    if median_num_idx <= 0:
        print (row['price'])
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for “calculate the median for frequency data” and ended up here and was disappointed that all manner of variations of asking that question basically produced the same result: treat the question as given a list of values and calculate the median.  While this may be strictly true, in most practical cases the frequency data reside (as in this example) within a list of ordered categories and, in non-trivial cases have a range of values within the categories.  Given this form, the question is not which interval contains the median so much as what would be a good estimate for where, within the interval, the median lies.  The US Census Bureau usually uses a technique of linear interpolation within the interval.  The initial basics are the same: locate the interval which contains the median.  Then create a linear interpolation (you could get fancy by spline interpolation and the like).  The code would look like:

```
def calc_quantile(freqs, bnds, aquantile):
"""
Calculate an interpolated quantile from distribution of 
frequencies counts (or percents) and their boundary 
definitions.  If there are n intervals the arrays are 
must be of length n+1.
freqs: length = n+1.  A distribution of numbers >= 0 
    representing counts, weights or percents.  For 
    consistency in indexing the first value, freq[0], 
    must be present but is not used (helps in 
    visualizing what is going on).
bnds:  - an array of n+1 numbers which provides the 
    definition of the boundary levels.  The assumed 
    relationship is that bnds[i] < bnds[i+1].  bnds[0] 
    represents the lower bound of freqs[1] and bnds[n] 
    is the upper bound for interval n.  These should 
    represent reasonable values. For example, the lower 
    bound (bnds[0]) for a first interval representing 
    adults under 20 years of age would be 18.  For a top 
    interval for adults 75 and older, might be 95.  When 
    all the population lies within an interval – the 
    returned estimate for the median would be average of 
    the top and bottom interval values.  In this example 
    if all values were in the top interval the result 
    would be 85, an ok general guess.  
q: the value of the quantile must be > 0 and < 1.  
    median = 0.5
"""
# Create the cumulative fractional distribution
cume = np.cumsum(x)/sum(x)
# find the median interval
i = np.argmax(cume >= aquantile)
# interpolate a value:
# calculate fraction of interval to cover
#    width of frequency interval:
#      cume[i] - cume[i-1])
#    amount under the quantile is:
#    (aquantile - cume[i-1])
f1 = (aquantile - cume[i-1])/(cume[i] - cume[i-1])
# the width of the bounds interval is:  wb = bnds[i] - 
# bnds[i-1]
# bnds[i] is upper bound of interval thus the quantile 
# is lower bound plus the desired fraction of the width 
# of the interval
return bnds[i-1] + f1*(bnds[i] - bnds[i-1])
```

Given the case provided then the following code would produce an answer of 31.0999 which, if the data are distributed in the interval, is a much more sane estimator than 40

```
calc_quantile([0, 16.76, 12.0, 4.1, 3.3], [0, 30, 40, 120, 200], 0.5)
```

or using a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Customer': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                         'Price': [200, 120, 40, 30],
                         'Quantity Sold': [3.3, 4.1, 12.0, 16.76]}
                        ).set_index('Customer')
df = df.sort_values('Price')

calc_quantile(np.insert(df['Quantity Sold'].values, 0, 0), np.insert(df.Price.values, 0, 0), 0.5)
```